# Too much disk space used by Apache Kudu for WALs

Tags: apache-kudu

I have a `hive table` that is of 2.7 MB (which is stored in a parquet format). When I use `impala-shell` to convert this hive table to `kudu`, I notice that the `/tserver/` folder size increases by around 300 MB. Upon exploring further, I see it is the `/tserver/wals/` folder that holds the majority of this increase. I am facing serious issues due to this. If a 2.7 MB file generates a 300 MB WAL, then I cannot really work on bigger data. Is there a solution to this?

My `kudu` version is `1.1.0` and impala is `2.7.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I never used KUDU but I'm able to Google on a few keywords, and read some documentation.

From the [Kudu configuration reference](https://kudu.apache.org/docs/configuration_reference.html) section *"Unsupported flags"*...

> --log_preallocate_segments
>  Whether the WAL should preallocate the entire segment before writing to it
>  Default true
>
> --log_segment_size_mb
>  The default segment size for log roll-overs, in MB
>  Default 64
>
> --log_min_segments_to_retain
>  The minimum number of past log segments to keep at all times, regardless of what is required for
>   durability. Must be at least 1.
>  Default 2
>
> --log_max_segments_to_retain
>  The maximum number of past log segments to keep at all times for the purposes of catching up other
>   peers.
>  Default 10

Looks like you have a *minimum* disk requirement of (2+1)x64 MB *per tablet*, for the WAL only. And it can grow up to 10x64 MB if some tablets are straggling and cannot catch up.

Plus some temp disk space for compaction etc. etc.

---

***[Edit]*** these default values have changed in **[Kudu 1.4](https://kudu.apache.org/releases/1.4.0/docs/release_notes.html)** (released in June 2017); quoting the Release Notes...

> The default size for Write Ahead Log (WAL) segments has been reduced
>   from 64MB to 8MB. Additionally, in the case that all replicas of a
>   tablet are fully up to date and data has been flushed from memory,
>   servers will now retain only a single WAL segment rather than two.
>   These changes are expected to **reduce the average consumption of disk
>   space** on the configured WAL disk **by 16x**